# CMD - Command to change front size

Tags: cmd, command

Is there a way to enter a command into cmd, and increase the front size, not the resolution?

Not by clicking on the properties, but by typing a command in the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the desired changes to the registry with `reg.exe`, but that will only affect new instances of `cmd.exe`, not the ones currently running. I don't think there is any builtin command line tool to change the font size on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the cmd prompt icon -> properties -> font... Change font from there.

The truetype fonts (I have consolas and Lucida console installed apparently) have font sizes.

[image: Cmd Prompt]